# Making Navigation View cover Toolbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

In my application I have a single activity and many fragments. In my activity layout I have added a `Toolbar` that I would like all of the nested fragments to have access to. Like so:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        ... />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/host_fragment"
        ... />

</LinearLayout>
```

Currently the navigation view, when pulled out, does not cover the the toolbar.

In one of my fragments I would like to have the `NavigationView` of a `DrawerLayout` cover the toolbar but I'm not sure how to do that since the `Toolbar` is in a parent view. Does this mean the activity cannot contain the `Toolbar` if I want such behavior?

Comment: "Does this mean the activity cannot contain the Toolbar if I want such behavior?" – Not necessarily, but the `Toolbar` does need to be inside the `DrawerLayout`'s main content. If you don't want to move the `Toolbar` into the `Fragment`s, you could put the `DrawerLayout` in the `Activity`'s layout, and lock the drawer closed on all but the one `Fragment`.

Comment: @MikeM. I was wondering if that might be the case. I wonder if there would be any performance issues doing something like or if it would be negligible since it is never shown.

Comment: Unless you've done something abnormal, it's just another couple of `ViewGroup`s. Also, while the drawer is shut, it's completely skipped in the layout and draw routines. If you're really concerned about it, you could do some hierarchy juggling when that particular `Fragment` is shown/hidden, so that the `DrawerLayout` is added/removed as needed, but that's gonna be a little unwieldy, and would likely affect performance when handling that `Fragment`. I'd only try that out of you do see some slowdown.

Comment: I'm not intimately familiar with how android does view rendering but what you say makes sense. I'll give that a try then, thanks!